# JPGraph barplot remove 0 values from GroupBarPlot

Tags: php, bar-chart, jpgraph

I have made a JPGraph graph with some values but sometimes my value is empty (0) like this example [image: jpgraph example]

I want to group the existing bars to the middle of the label. For example at the second label (the green and red bar), I want to stick these two bars together at the center of the label. Now you see the empty value of the yellow in the middle of the two bars.

Is it possibile to remove the empty bar from the plot, because if I remove the empty values from the plot array, JPGraph noticed the incorrect length of the arrays and throws an error or don't print the plot.

Answer (score 0):

```
$graph = new Graph\PieGraph(400, 300);
$p1 = new Plot\PiePlotC($data);
$p1->value->HideZero(true);
$graph->Add($p1);
$graph->Stroke();
```